# How to use the _.once() function in lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am have tried to use the once function in lodash as follows:

```
_.once(pageTwoSegmentEvent);

_.once(() => {
  pageTwoSegmentEvent();
})
```

I have also tried importing only the once function from lodash and not the _

```
once(pageTwoSegmentEvent);

once(() => {
  pageTwoSegmentEvent();
});
```

But the function pageTwoSegmentEvent never actually gets called.  However, if I remove the once function that its wrapped in and just call it like normal then it works but gets called too many times.  Does anyone know how to get the once function from lodash to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't use `_.once` like that.  You use the new function that `_.once` returns.

```js
function foo() {
  console.log("foo");
}

const oncedFoo = _.once(foo);

oncedFoo();
oncedFoo();
oncedFoo();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried this and although it does work in getting the function called it calls it repeatedly.  I thought it should only call it once??

Comment: The new function that is returned by once will only call the function you provide once. Nothing stops something else with a reference to the original function from calling it as many times as it wants.

Answer (score 2):

`_.once` returns a function, so you have to call the returned function

Try doing

```
_.once(pageTwoSegmentEvent)();
```

(note the parenthesis at the end)